# Deploying Google Cloud Endpoints configuration fails Google API Linter recommendations

Tags: google-cloud-platform, protocol-buffers, grpc, google-cloud-endpoints, google-api-linter

**Update:** [Cloud Endpoints Portal is being deprecated](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/deprecations/endpoints-portal-deprecation) and will no longer be available after 21 March 2023.

---

After following [Deploying the Endpoints configuration](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/grpc/deploy-endpoints-config) I have successfully deployed my compiled `.proto` file and gRPC API configuration file.

Great. I decided to be be a good citizen and use [Google's API Linter](https://linter.aip.dev/) on my `.proto`.

This resulted in a number of recommendations to include various annotations. The annotations required new `proto` imports;

**Before**

```proto
syntax = "proto3";
package api.v1;

// Request message for Get method.
message GetFooRequest {
  // The field will contain name of the resource requested.
  string name = 1;
}

...blah,blah
```

**After**

```proto
syntax = "proto3";
package api.v1;

import "google/api/annotations.proto";
import "google/api/client.proto";
import "google/api/field_behavior.proto";
import "google/api/resource.proto";

// Request message for Get method.
message GetFooRequest {
  // The field will contain name of the resource requested.
  string name = 1 [
    (google.api.field_behavior) = REQUIRED,
    (google.api.resource_reference).type = "api.v1.HelloWorld/Foo"
  ];
}
...blah,blah
```

The annotations require four new proto files to be imported:

```proto
import "google/api/annotations.proto";
import "google/api/client.proto";
import "google/api/field_behavior.proto";
import "google/api/resource.proto";
```

All are part of [Google's Common API](https://github.com/googleapis/api-common-protos/tree/master/google/api) protos, therefore I cloned [the repo](https://github.com/googleapis/api-common-protos) into `/Users/Jack/api-common-protos/` with:

```
git clone https://github.com/googleapis/api-common-protos.git
```

...and include it when compiling my `.proto` file:

```
python3 -m grpc_tools.protoc --proto_path=api
                             --proto_path=/Users/Jack/api-common-protos/google
                             api/v1/foo.proto
```

No errors. Great. Finally I deploy the API:

```
gcloud endpoints services deploy api_descriptor.pb api-config.yaml
```

This completes. However, the Developer Portal now shows:

```
We encountered the following errors while processing this API specification:

API parse error: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/tmp/google/api/client.proto'

Please correct these errors and try again.
```

Scrot:

[image]

If I remove the annotation (and required imports), the Endpoints Developer Portal for my API works fine.

Comment: It seems that the "protoc" is looking for the file `/tmp/google/api/client.proto` and this file in your cloned repository is under `/Users/Jack/api-common-protos/google/api/client.proto`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in the developer portal. I have reported it to the team responsible. See [Google's API Linter suggestions with Google Cloud Endpoints?](https://groups.google.com/g/google-cloud-endpoints/c/xSch_nbbpwc) which I posted to `google-cloud-endpoints@googlegroups.com`.

Comment: As a fun note, since you added those, you can use some other tooling to auto-generate client libraries: see these for [Python](https://github.com/googleapis/gapic-generator-python), [Ruby](https://github.com/googleapis/gapic-generator-ruby), [TypeScript](https://github.com/googleapis/gapic-generator-typescript), [Go](https://github.com/googleapis/gapic-generator-go), and [C#](https://github.com/googleapis/gapic-generator-csharp).

Comment: @nareddyt, did you get a solution to this issue?

Comment: @nareddyt is there any update on this? I'm kind of surprised it isn't higher priority given that the Endpoints Portal remains unusable until this is fixed.

Comment: No, the issue was not fixed yet. Other community users workaround this by using a script to scrub out the annotations before deployment to Cloud Endpoints: https://groups.google.com/g/google-cloud-endpoints/c/gjvRGY2HU7M/m/mnNouUaoAQAJ

Comment: why is this not fixed yet?

Comment: I've updated the question with a notice that [Cloud Endpoints Portal is deprecated](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/deprecations/endpoints-portal-deprecation),

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not much effort to temporarily work around the issue:

```
cp /Users/Jack/api-common-protos/google/api/client.proto /tmp/google/api/client.proto
```

Then the file will be available, where it is being expected - despite not being put there automatically.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't fix it for me. Do you still have the issue?